# Problems with Laravel 5.6 Vue.js e o app.js (404)

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I use laravel 5.6, vue.js, apache.

Erro: 
 `GET https://alphi.com.br/js/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404`

Did you upload the file in your server? **yes**

Does the build provide a minified version with a hash added? **no**

The app.js is not recognized in my frontend application.

What I tried and did not work:

- folder permission is correct
- mix did not advance anything
- I changed the folder, but error persist.

Configuration webpack.mix.js:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
.version();
```

Can anybody help me. I searched all over the internet and found nothing to help me.

Thank you

Comment: what is the folder structure of your project and what is the build configuration?

Comment: public/js/app.js

and configuration:

webpack.mix.js
`
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .version();
`

Comment: 404 means the file is not found? Did you upload the file in your server? Does the build provide a minified version with a hash added?

Comment: 404 means the file is not found? **yes**
Did you upload the file in your server? **yes**
Does the build provide a minified version with a hash added? **no**

Comment: well the correct url would be `/js/app.js` (without **public**) but this also gives 404

Comment: can you post your routes.php configuration?

Comment: The `app.js` is in the `resources/assets/js` folder when compiling (`npm run dev` or `npm run prod`) it throws `app.js` into the `public/js/app.js` folder.

I'm trying to implement vue.js in my laravel project 5.6

Comment: sure. Is the app.js file there when you run build? If so what are the contents of the file? Plus please share your routes configuration

Comment: are you running on apache or nginx? All these are needed information added to your question if you want an answer

Comment: @NikosM. which one? I have some route files

Comment: web routes, in laravel they would be `/routes/web.php`

Comment: are you running on apache or nginx? **apache**

Comment: it's a very large file

Comment: I wiould recommend to update your question and add all these things that you have added as comments plus the routes, maybe there is some route conflict

Comment: Sorry, I updated with Apache. I'm new here and thank you for your help. What should I look for to find this conflict?

Comment: Maybe some route is configured wrong and overrides the app.js path. Also try to [clear the cache](https://tecadmin.net/clear-cache-laravel-5/)

Comment: I had already found this article and done as I said it, but it did not solve my problem.

Comment: I try to run and than:

`php artisan route:cache` 
Route cache cleared!

`In Route.php line 880:`

`Unable to prepare route [clear-cache] for serialization. Uses Closure.`

Comment: is there a version added in your app.js build file?

Comment: I think not. I'm a _beginner_ in vue.js.

Comment: If you use `.version()` in Laravel-mix, you should use `<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>`

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution for this thread

instead of using this

```
<script src="{{  mix('js/app.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

try this

```
<script src="{{ asset( mix('js/app.js')) }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

-add the asset function

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you use `.version()` in Laravel-Mix, you should use in your blade

```
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

..because it's has a versioned name instead. Same for stylesheet path:

`{{ mix ('css/app.css') }}`

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mix#versioning-and-cache-busting

Comment: I did this, but it had not worked. it worked only after they messed up the server. accredited that it is something about permission. thank you